# file upload link in drop down - HTML

Tags: html, file-upload, drop-down-menu

I need an HTML code for a drop down button, which have a link file-upload , which will open the file upload box.
I have the HTML code as below, but it's not working. Whats the problem ?

```
<html>
<script type='text/javascript'src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js?ver=1.4.2"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="ssssssss.css">

<body>
<select id="uploadFile">
<option value="1"></option>
<option value="2"><input type="file" name="something" id="fileUploadField" />File</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">

$('#fileUploadField').click(function(e){
$('#fileUploadField').click();
e.preventDefault();
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You cant add html code in an option item (cf: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_option.asp).

What have to create a drop down menu with css (cf: http://line25.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu), then you can add an input type file tag.

Comment: First of all thanks for the answer... But it;s not what i am asking for. Can you please run the code i posted and when i click file.. it must open file upload box..also allignment

Comment: I ran your code, then i have the "upload box", but... what is not working ?

Comment: I think his problem is while clicking on the file(option item), the upload file dialogue is not getting opened.